# Publish Failing for pages in Tridion 2013 in "Deploying" phase

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1

Below is the error I am getting when trying to publish my pages. Not sure where to start looking. Log files do not give any errors. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image: Publish error]

### cd_core log:

```
2014-09-16 05:48:01,495 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2014-09-16 05:48:01,495 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-73175-66560 creating new transaction state
2014-09-16 05:48:01,510 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-73175-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\temp\tcm_0-73175-66560.Content\transaction.xml
2014-09-16 05:48:01,510 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2014-09-16 05:48:01,510 DEBUG DeployerTransactionDTO - Adding destination=qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA== to transaction with id=null
2014-09-16 05:48:01,526 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,526 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2014-09-16 05:48:01,526 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Creating DestinationProgressWorker for destination: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA== because of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,526 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2014-09-16 05:48:01,526 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA== because of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: "my path name" reason: Service Unavailable
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: "my path name" reason: Service Unavailable
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Finished retrieving active transactions at destination: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA== because of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[us\sptmtsuser], URL[my path name]] available: 3
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG DestinationControllerSlotChecker - In progress transactions on deployer side: 0, maximum window size on the deployer side: 20
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 INFO  DestinationControllerSlotChecker - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560, destinationId: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA==.
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA==
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 INFO  TransportService - Can transport for transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560 is : true
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-73175-66560
2014-09-16 05:48:01,557 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-73175-66560.Content/Binaries/MedSuppInfo/Images/arrow_tcm79-35063.gif
2014-09-16 05:48:01,573 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-73175-66560.Content/Binaries/MedSuppInfo/Images/herointerior_couplelaptop_tcm79-35071.jpg
```

### cd_deployer log:

```
2014-09-16 03:10:53,532 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ReferenceEntryWorker@1a2c0e83 took: 16
2014-09-16 03:10:53,532 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ComponentPresentationWorker@69c3959e this is worker 305 of: 306
2014-09-16 03:10:53,532 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ComponentPresentationWorker@69c3959e took: 0
2014-09-16 03:10:53,532 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ComponentPresentationMetaWorker@4a522c56 this is worker 306 of: 306
2014-09-16 03:10:53,641 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ComponentPresentationMetaWorker@4a522c56 took: 109
2014-09-16 03:10:53,641 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-73154-66560
2014-09-16 03:10:53,641 INFO  CommitPhase - Committing transaction: tcm:0-73154-66560
2014-09-16 03:10:53,688 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-73154-66560
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 INFO  CommitPhase - Executing phase: post-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-73154-66560
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: post-transaction
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-transaction
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: post-transaction
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Checking if transaction is completed: tcm:0-73154-66560 is true
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-73154-66560
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-73154-66560 in 15459 ms.
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 INFO  TransactionManager - Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-73154-66560 and type: CONTENT
2014-09-16 03:10:53,703 DEBUG TransactionManager - The transport package has transaction control: COMMIT
2014-09-16 03:10:53,937 INFO  TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-73154-66560 with type: CONTENT
2014-09-16 03:10:53,937 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing from queue Deployment package: tcm:0-73154-66560 with type: CONTENT.
2014-09-16 03:10:53,937 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-73154-66560 with type: CONTENT.
2014-09-16 03:10:53,937 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removed exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-73154-66560 with type: CONTENT.
```

Comment: Could you add some more useful information ? can you post the storage config file. Are you logging on the deployer side? Could you log in "debug" mode, and post the logfiles as well ?

Comment: on logging through "debug" mode we get the following error:                                  DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: qOtOznY9hJ16kiZTkd6+aA== because of transaction: tcm:0-73175-66560
ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector- An unexpected error occurred while polling: "My Path" reason: Service Unavailable
2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: "My Path" reason: Service Unavailable

Comment: The "service unavailable" message hints that there is a problem with the httpupload website. Can you check in the windows event log if you see any IIS related warnings or errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did publishing ever work before? Are your logs from the deployer side? They look more like CM side. Check the logback file on your deployer and make sure to check the logfiles referenced there

This can be a gazillion things but for some reason the following two happen to me very often

- Disk Full
- Write permissions on the incoming folder

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the first post, the logs are in DEBUG mode, double-check all logback.xml files are indeed set to DEBUG.

Here are some more troubleshooting tips:

1. Be clear about what version you are running on both CM and CD, and that they match long term.
2. Set all logs to DEBUG
3. Restart all services (or sites if you're running the Deployer in IIS/Tomcat), COM+ and reset/restart the associated servers (IIS/Tomcat)
4. Check the services are actually working (especially Publisher, Transport and Deployer).
5. If you still see error messages in the publishing queue, but not in logs, check if there is a rogue deployer active somewhere.  For that, you can search the file system for cd_deployer_conf.xml and/or look in the QUEUE_CONSUMERS table for more than one "Deploy queue", QUEUE_ID = 2

   6. Also good to check are the Tridion and Tridion Content Manager window logs
   7. Another good source to check is www.sdltridionworld.com, login and visit the hotfixes section, these are organized by system version, so they're easy to find

Comment: while all of your troubleshooting tips are very useful in general, I personally would not start with setting the logs to debug. The deployment failure is an error, so that will show up in the log (provided you are looking at the right log). Only if the error message does not hold enough information, it can be useful to put logging in debug (keeping your log clean of debug messages can make it easier to spot the actual error line).

Answer (score 1):

Your cd_core log contains the following error:

> 2014-09-16 05:48:01,542 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: "my path name" reason: Service Unavailable

Note that if you would have your log settings on ERROR only rather than DEBUG, that might have been easier to spot.

If I'm not mistaking the "my path name" is referring to the Destination Name set in your Publication Target. The protocol wis set to HTTPS and it appears that the service specified in there is not available, so you might have some network connectivity issues, or your HTTP(S) Deployer website might be down.

Interesting detail is that the error occured on polling, which is what is done last to read back the status of the deployment. It might actually be so that your Publish/Deploy action went through successfully, and your content is published and deployed. But the status notification has failed, so the CD and CM side were unable to communicate that to eachother.

In any case, you need to investigate this service connectivity issue and resolve it of course.